# Cantor ternary sets problem

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am self studying math and I'm new to MSE.
I was reading an old real analysis book and confronted this exercise:

> If $C$ is the ternary Cantor set, prove that:
>
> 1. $C \cap (C+2/3)$ is uncountable
> 2. $C \cap (C+1/3) = \{1/3,2/3\}$

I tried to solve 1. with Cantor diagonalization but I failed.

I have no idea how about 2., I'd appreciate if someone helped me with it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $C\cap (C+2/3)=C\cap[2/3,1]$, while $C\cap (C+1/3)\subset C\cap[1/3,2/3]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I really appreciate